# Replace keys of a nested dictionary with the value of another dictionary(where keys of two dict are equal)), value for a key may be list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dict, dict1 and dict2, I want to construct new dict(or manipulate dict1) with key-value pairs as(value of dict2:value of dict1 [where key of dict one and key of dict2 are same]) , value of a key may be list of dicts(as you will see in input example)

**INPUT IS**

```
dict1 = {"key1":{"key3":"value1","key2":"value2","key4":{"key5":"value3","key6":{"key7":"value4","key8":{"key9":"value5","key10":"value6","key55":"value7"}},"key11":{"key12":"value8","key13":"value9"},"key14":[{"key15":"value10","key16":"value11","key17":"value12"},{"key15":"value13","key16":"value14","key17":"value15"}]}}}

dict2 = {"key1":"ab","key2":"bc","key3":"cd","key4":"de","key5":"ef","key6":"fg","key7":"gh","key8":"hi","key9":"ij","key10":"jk","key55":"kl","key11":"lm","key12":"mn","key13":"no","key14":"op","key15":"pq","key16":"qr","key17":"qs"}
```

**My function is**

```
def walk(dict1, dict2):
    output = {}
    for key, value in dict1.iteritems():

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            output[dict2[key]] = walk(value, dict2)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            output[dict2[key]] = walk_list(value, dict2)
        else:
            output[dict2[key]] = value
    return output

def walk_list(sublist, dict2):
    output = []
    for i in sublist:

        if isinstance(i, dict):
            output = walk(i, dict2)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            output = walk_list(i, dict2)
        else:
            output.append((key, value))
    return output

output = walk(dict1, dict2)
output = json.dumps(output)
print output
```

**OUTPUT AM GETTING IS**

```
 {"ab": {"de": {"lm": {"mn": "value8", "no": "value9"}, "ef": "value3", "fg": {"hi": {"ij": "value5", "jk": "value6", "kl": "value7"}, "gh": "value4"}, "op": {"pq": "value13", "qs": "value15", "qr": "value14"}}, "bc": "value2", "cd": "value1"}}
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT IS**

```
 {"ab":{"cd":"value1","bc":"value2","de":{"ef":"value3","fg":{"gh":"value4","hi":{"ij":"value5","jk":"value6","kl":"value7"}},"lm":{"mn":"value8","no":"value9"},"op":[{"pq":"value10","qr":"value11","qs":"value12"},{"pq":"value13","qr":"value14","qs":"value15"}]}}}
```

Please fix my code.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple solution that performs the recursive step very early and as such has a very simple logic:

```
def translateKeys (obj, keyNames):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {keyNames.get(k, k): translateKeys(v, keyNames) for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [translateKeys(v, keyNames) for v in obj]
    else:
        return obj
```

Instead of expecting a certain type, it just accepts anything (dictionary, list, or whatever) and works on the items of it, calling itself for every value. This avoids having to iterate through `obj` itself and check the value of each item within the loop.

Used on your example data:

```
>>> dict1 = {"key1":{"key3":"value1","key2":"value2","key4":{"key5":"value3","key6":{"key7":"value4","key8":{"key9":"value5","key10":"value6","key55":"value7"}},"key11":{"key12":"value8","key13":"value9"},"key14":[{"key15":"value10","key16":"value11","key17":"value12"},{"key15":"value13","key16":"value14","key17":"value15"}]}}}
>>> dict2 = {"key1":"ab","key2":"bc","key3":"cd","key4":"de","key5":"ef","key6":"fg","key7":"gh","key8":"hi","key9":"ij","key10":"jk","key55":"kl","key11":"lm","key12":"mn","key13":"no","key14":"op","key15":"pq","key16":"qr","key17":"qs"}
>>> expected =  {"ab":{"cd":"value1","bc":"value2","de":{"ef":"value3","fg":{"gh":"value4","hi":{"ij":"value5","jk":"value6","kl":"value7"}},"lm":{"mn":"value8","no":"value9"},"op":[{"pq":"value10","qr":"value11","qs":"value12"},{"pq":"value13","qr":"value14","qs":"value15"}]}}}
>>> result = translateKeys(dict1, dict2)
>>> result
{'ab': {'de': {'fg': {'gh': 'value4', 'hi': {'ij': 'value5', 'jk': 'value6', 'kl': 'value7'}}, 'op': [{'qr': 'value11', 'pq': 'value10', 'qs': 'value12'}, {'qr': 'value14', 'pq': 'value13', 'qs': 'value15'}], 'ef': 'value3', 'lm': {'no': 'value9', 'mn': 'value8'}}, 'cd': 'value1', 'bc': 'value2'}}
>>> result == expected
True
```

---

If you want to invert this translation, you can just invert `keyNames` and perform the translation on the result instead:

```
>>> result = translateKeys(dict1, dict2)
>>> invertedKeyNames = {v: k for k, v in dict2.items()}
>>> original = translateKeys(result, invertedKeyNames)
>>> original == dict1
True
```

Comment: is it generalised? means will it work for any JSON? like value of a key may be a simple value, list, dict any other nested valid combination of lists and dict according to JSON structure?

Comment: Yeah, it should work with `obj` being any kind of deserialized JSON object. Since [JSON objects](http://www.json.org/) can only be objects (=dictionaries), arrays (=lists), or values (numbers, strings, `true`, `false`, or `null`), and we handle the recursion of objects and arrays (since those are the only types that can contain other JSON objects which may need key translation), it should work with any valid object that comes from JSON.

Comment: can you also provide another function to retrive dict1 by using dict2 and result?

Comment: Sure, you just need to invert the `dict2` dictionary, so the mapping is in the other direction and then apply it on the previous result. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves the riddle using one function only

```
def walk(dict1, dict2):
    res = dict()
    for k,v in dict1.items():
        if isinstance(v,list):
            newv = [walk(x, dict2) for x in v]
        elif isinstance(v,dict):
            newv = walk(v, dict2)
        else:
            newv = v
        res[dict2.get(k, k)] = newv # keep the same key if not present in dict2
    return res

expected = {"ab":{"cd":"value1","bc":"value2","de":{"ef":"value3","fg":{"gh":"value4","hi":{"ij":"value5","jk":"value6","kl":"value7"}},"lm":{"mn":"value8","no":"value9"},"op":[{"pq":"value10","qr":"value11","qs":"value12"},{"pq":"value13","qr":"value14","qs":"value15"}]}}}

output = walk(dict1, dict2)
print(output)
print(output == expected)
```

as it produces

```
{'ab': {'de': {'lm': {'no': 'value9', 'mn': 'value8'}, 'ef': 'value3', 'fg': {'hi': {'ij': 'value5', 'kl': 'value7', 'jk': 'value6'}, 'gh': 'value4'}, 'op': [{'qr': 'value11', 'qs': 'value12', 'pq': 'value10'}, {'qr': 'value14', 'qs': 'value15', 'pq': 'value13'}]}, 'cd': 'value1', 'bc': 'value2'}}
True
```

Basically it examines every value in the dictionary:

- if it is a list of values, it applies itself to every item in the list
- if it is a dictionary it applies itself to it
- if it is a literal value then it uses it

EDIT:

in case the input dictionaries are not only dictionaries after all, but can be any acceptable json element (e.g. list, dict, value) that can become more generalised

```
def walk(obj, keys):
    if isinstance(obj,list):
        return [walk(x, keys) for x in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj,dict):
        return {keys.get(k, k): walk(v, keys) for k,v in obj.items()}
    else:
        return obj
```

which is exactly what @Poke had answered from the beginning, kudos to him.

EDIT2:

in case you want to revert back to the original dictionary `dict1`, provided the values are all disjoint (i.e. the `dict2` mapping is a [bijective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)), you can do

```
back2dict1 = walk(output, {v:k for k,v in dict2.items()})
print(back2dict1)
print(back2dict1 == dict1)
```

which produces

```
{'key1': {'key3': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key4': {'key5': 'value3', 'key11': {'key12': 'value8', 'key13': 'value9'}, 'key14': [{'key15': 'value10', 'key16': 'value11', 'key17': 'value12'}, {'key15': 'value13', 'key16': 'value14', 'key17': 'value15'}], 'key6': {'key7': 'value4', 'key8': {'key10': 'value6', 'key55': 'value7', 'key9': 'value5'}}}}}
True
```

Comment: `res[dict2[k]] = newv` should be `res[dict2.get(k, k)] = newv` to handle the case when `k not in dict2`.

Comment: @DanD. yes, thank you for pointing that out. I had thought about it, but didn't write it down in the end

Comment: is it generalised? means will it work for any JSON? like value of a key may be a simple value, list, dict any other nested valid combination of lists and dict according to JSON structure?

Comment: BTW, you might want to update the title and description of your question to reflect your requirements more accurately. It would help future readers with the same problem

Comment: BTW thanks for your input, can you also provide another function to retrive dict1 by using dict2 and result?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is to do with your walk_list function with the output variable being assigned rather than appended to. This is my version:

```
dict1 = {"key1":{"key3":"value1","key2":"value2","key4":{"key5":"value3","key6":{"key7":"value4","key8":{"key9":"value5","key10":"value6","key55":"value7"}},"key11":{"key12":"value8","key13":"value9"},"key14":[{"key15":"value10","key16":"value11","key17":"value12"},{"key15":"value13","key16":"value14","key17":"value15"}]}}}
dict2 = {"key1":"ab","key2":"bc","key3":"cd","key4":"de","key5":"ef","key6":"fg","key7":"gh","key8":"hi","key9":"ij","key10":"jk","key55":"kl","key11":"lm","key12":"mn","key13":"no","key14":"op","key15":"pq","key16":"qr","key17":"qs"}

def walk(dict1, dict2):
    output = {}
    for key, value in dict1.iteritems():

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            outVal = walk(value, dict2)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            outVal = walk_list(value, dict2)
        else:
            outVal = value
        output[dict2[key]] = outVal

    return output

def walk_list(sublist, dict2):
    output = []
    for i in sublist:
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            outVal = walk(i, dict2)
        elif isinstance(i, list):
            outVal = walk_list(i, dict2)
        else:
            outVal = i
        output.append(outVal)

    return output            

mine = walk(dict1, dict2)
expecting = {"ab":{"cd":"value1","bc":"value2","de":{"ef":"value3","fg":{"gh":"value4","hi":{"ij":"value5","jk":"value6","kl":"value7"}},"lm":{"mn":"value8","no":"value9"},"op":[{"pq":"value10","qr":"value11","qs":"value12"},{"pq":"value13","qr":"value14","qs":"value15"}]}}}

print mine == expecting
```

Comment: is it generalised? means will it work for any JSON? like value of a key may be a simple value, list, dict any other nested valid combination of lists and dict according to JSON structure?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. :)

Comment: BTW thanks for your input, can you also provide another function to retrive dict1 by using dict2 and result?